# Travelling during Diwali in India, good idea to book ahead?

Tags: india, transportation, accommodation, public-holidays, diwali

We will be in Northern India in November 2023. We will travel by train/bus and don't plan to book hotels ahead as we like to be very flexible with our travels.

The Diwali holiday is on November 12th in 2023, and festivities may last several days.

Do a lot of locals travel during this period? Will it be more difficult to find hotels and seats on transport?

If so, should we stay away from certain places where big crowds are gathering for special festivities?

Comment: Do a lot of locals travel during this period? A lot of locals travel at any time of year, and the trains tend to be [packed](https://www.businessinsider.com/indias-trains-are-insanely-crowded-2016-2?r=US&IR=T). Always book.

Comment: OT: in the third picture in the link, I notice that the train driver won't be able to see the track or signals ahead. Perhaps the man in the orange shirt waving a green flag is signalling "a train is coming through" :)

Answer (score 2):

Diwali is a huge festival in India, and folks tend to zoom off to celebrate with their families or take a break during that time. Probably there will be quite a number of people around, and finding accommodation and transport may be more challenging. It would be a great idea to plan ahead and grab those spots early to sidestep any issues.